# RangeError (index): Index out of range

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, range, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a program of Binary search using the recursion method in the dart. I am getting "Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 12: 44" ERROR.

CODE:-

```
void main(){
List array=[2,3,4,6,8,10,14,16,20,26,28,30];

var num=14;

int len=array.length;
print(len);

var start = array[0];
var end = array[len-1];

Binarysearch(array,start,end,num);


}

Binarysearch(List a, var start, var end, var x){

 int temp=0;

int mid= end+(end-start)/2;

if (a[mid]==x){
  temp=1;
}

else if(a[mid]>x){
  Binarysearch( a, start, mid-1, x );
}
  else if (a[mid]<x){
    Binarysearch( a, end, mid+1, x);
}


if(temp==1){
print("Your item is in the  index");
}
else{
print("your item is not in the index");
}


}
```

Comment: value of x in any of if-else statement appearing as null, that's why range error is appearing,

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you will most certanly get "Index out of range" because you are calculating the index for the list via this piece of code:
int mid= end+(end-start)/2;

If you take the first iteration where end is 30 and start is 2 you will get the index 44 and then ask the list give me the 44th item (which doesn't exist).